# Bit bucket enterprise edition rest api reference

Tags: bitbucket-api, confluence-rest-api, bitbucket-server

I am not able to find the API documentation for Bitbucket enterprise edition.
I tried referring to the API documentation given in the following link
https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/ but none of these api seem to work.

The URL structure of our bitbucket server is of the form
https://bitbucket-mycompany.com

I am able to hit the below rest end point

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/project1/repos/repo1/commits?
```

But other than this none of the rest-end points seem to return any data.(404 not found)

Here is the reference that i used
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html

I am looking for the right usage of the rest API's mentioned in the documentation